# How to open view in core php from controller of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have my php project  in following structure

```
> myProject  
   ->memberList.php  
   ->memberEntry.php  
   ->ci
       ->application
           ->controller             
                ->siteController        
           ->model      
           ->view
```

I am using both core php and Codeigniter framework for my project named 'myProject.' I have added CI framework inside folder named 'ci'. Most of the code is in core php and for some forms only i have use ci framework. I have to open a form named memberEntry.php from siteController.How can this be done?
My controller code is like this:

```
public function auditDetails(){
    ..........
    $this->load->view('../../../memberEntry', $data);
}
```

Comment: I tried the same, It's working for me. just check rout code in config.php file.

Comment: my code $this->load->view('../../../memberEntry', $data); is not redirecting to memberEntry form.

Comment: It's should be redirect. did you check $route in config/routes.php file?

Comment: i have added $route['siteController/auditDetails'] = 'siteController/auditDetails'; in routes.php

Comment: call with .php extension and see $this->load->view('../../../memberEntry.php', $data);

Comment: where is `index.php` for codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your structure:

[image]

go in to `index.php` and change the following variables

```
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" directory.
 * Set the path if it is not in the same directory as this file.
 */
    $system_path = 'ci/system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * directory than the default one you can set its name here. The directory
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server. If you do,
 * use an absolute (full) server path.
 * For more info please see the user guide:
 *
 * https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $application_folder = 'ci/application';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * VIEW DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want to move the view directory out of the application
 * directory, set the path to it here. The directory can be renamed
 * and relocated anywhere on your server. If blank, it will default
 * to the standard location inside your application directory.
 * If you do move this, use an absolute (full) server path.
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $view_folder = './';
```

then you can just load view as normal `$this->load->view('welcome_message');`

---

I would also suggest not using camelCase definitions for files and switch over to Something_more_codeigniter_friendly.php. This is **required** for controllers.